# WSO2 EI and sending message to VFS with RSA keys

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

What's the WSO2 way of sending messages to VFS using RSA SSH private/public key for authentication instead of a standard username/password?
The documentation describes the opposite direction clearly (so getting a file from VFS server in Proxy service) with a service's parameter `transport.vfs.SFTPIdentities`. But how to achieve the same in a sequence sending message to outbound system? I assume that there is some trick...

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find the exact place the parameter is set or whether the transport sender supports it. But if the transport sender doesn't allow you to set this, you can definitely use the [File Connector](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-file) which supports [this](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-file/blob/release-3.0.3/src/main/resources/file/filecreate-template.xml#L30).